# Refresh UI for a countdown timer

Tags: android, timer, countdown

I need to show on the UI a countdown of an expiry date.

I get the countdown on a new Runnable() but how do I keep the TextView refreshed?

Any other advises to implement this?

Thanks

Comment: how to help/suggest you without seeing your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think one of the best ways you have to implement what you want is to use AsyncTask (refer to painless threading: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/05/painless-threading.html.

You can then use the method [onProgressUpdate](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onProgressUpdate%28Progress...%29) from [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) to update your UI thread.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [Updating the UI from a Timer](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/timed-ui-updates.html)

Comment: Thx @Rajesh, I just couldn't find such an obvious piece of doc. Just what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

You could also send a broadcast to the main thread when the condition for update is met.